# css map area layering

Tags: css, image, dictionary, area

**Is there a way to "layer" image map areas?**

I have 2 areas, say circles, overlapping each other. One is twice the area of the other.

Setting z-index style attribute does NOT appear to work.

Is there perhaps another way to achieve this?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also a duplicate of previous question ALSO put on hold for the same reason - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602142/css-image-map-area-layering

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is extremely important the order of the area tag matter:

```
<img src="images/some.gif" alt="" usemap="#someMap" id="someImage" />
<map id="someMap" name="someMap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="x1,y1,x2,y2,20" href="locations/state_results.php?StateName=NT" 
        onmouseover="MM_swapImage('someImage','','images/small_Square.gif',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" >
    <area shape="circle" coords="10,10,40"
        href="locations/state_results.php?StateName=WA" 
        onmouseover="MM_swapImage('someImage','','images/bigCircle.gif',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" >
</map>
```

**It is important that the smaller area comes first.**